# How to add dll which i got in the same solution into tfs?

Tags: dll, tfs

I'm making program which contains few projects. One of them is dll, which is used in another project of the same solution. I have no idea how to attach this dll into tfs, while i can change content of it everytime and after rebuild i got new dll.

Firstly i've got something like this:

```
IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"C:\Path\To\DLL\dllName.dll");
```

It worked great when i was working on it by myself. But I don't know how to connect this things in TFS. Where to put this library, and how to make it connected with developing version of dll.

Comment: it needs to be a relative path.

Comment: you can create a folder "Assemblies" in the project the dll is used. Set the build output of the "dll" project to this "Assemblies" folder and then add the reference of the dll from the "Assemblies" folder to the project which needs dll. After that, you can include the "Assemblies" folder and its dll contents to the tfs. This way, everytime you change the dll project, the output will be in the "Assemblies" folder which TFS monitors

Comment: no problem(: did it solved your issue?